# Rename mailer-daemon in postfix

Tags: email, postfix, daemon

Is there a way to rename the email adress of mailer-daemon@example.com to some other (e.g. mailer-angel@example.com)? I need that the sender of the "Non delivery report" has other email adress than mailer-daemon@example.com

The change in /etc/postfix/main.cf of empty_address_recipient = MAILER-DAEMON does not seem to be a working solution.

Answer (score 3):

As mandated by RFC5321 Section 4.5.5, DSNs MUST be sent with a NULL Return-Path (or MAIL FROM) sender.

The From: header MAILER-DAEMON@example.com is set by the **receiving** MTA, based on the NULL sender address.

Comment: Thanks for reply, now I understand why my solution does not work. Anyway, What I would like to do is to rename the mailer-daemon on our own domain so that our email-accounts get the non-delivery report from another address than mailer-daemon@ourdomain.com